# BingMapsTask on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, bing-maps, windows-phone-8.1

On Windows Phone 8, we call phone's Bing map app with c# using BingMapsTask . But Windows Phone 8.1, BingMapsTask won't work?

How to call Bing Maps on Windows Phone 8.1? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, you can use Bing map by Launcher:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync
(
    new Uri("bingmaps:?lvl=10&where=London", UriKind.Absolute)
);
```

there are 2 parameters in it: lvl and where, You should put ZoomLevel and the City Name in it.

This is MSDN doc link: [URI scheme for Bing Maps app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635237.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its a solution for this problem.